# Gradle error: "Could not find property '...' on root project '...'

Tags: java, groovy, gradle, build.gradle

I try do build my Java project with `Gradle` and I'm getting the following:

```
Starting Build
Settings evaluated using settings file 'C:\Users\MyName\Java8\MyJavaProject\settings.gradle'.
Projects loaded. Root project using build file 'C:\Users\MyName\Java8\MyJavaProject\build.gradle'.
Included projects: [root project 'MyJavaProject']
Evaluating root project 'MyJavaProject' using build file 'C:\Users\MyName\Java8\MyJavaProject\build.gradle'.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\MyName\Java8\MyJavaProject\build.gradle' line: 25

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'MyJavaProject'.
> Could not find property 'myJavaPackage' on root project 'MyJavaProject'.
```

Line **25** of `build.gradle`: `mainClassName = myJavaPackage.runner.MainRunner`

In `settings.gradle` I have: `rootProject.name = 'MyJavaProject'`

*Project directory structure*:

`MyJavaProject`-> `main` -> `java` -> `myJavaPackage` -> `runner` -> `MainRunner`

I'm using **Gradle 11.1**

Since the stack trace is huge I did not post the entire one.

Close to the bottom it shows:

> Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not find
>   property 'myJavaPackage' on root project 'MyJavaProject'.

I searched for this type of error but the answers were mostly about upgrading Gradle from an old version to a newer one.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Correct is (notice the quotes):

```
mainClassName = "myJavaPackage.runner.MainRunner"
```

Comment: Yes, that was it.  Can't believe I couldn't see it myself.  Thank you!